# Plotting the results of a Fourier transform with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

My university project consists of taking a clean corpus of sound data in `.wav` form, adding Gaussian noise using [numpy.random.normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html), saving it then using [an rfft function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html) which I would like to plot in a graph. As you probably expect using pyplot's `plot()` gives me the error `ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part`
 which gives me a simple 2D graph which isn't what my supervisor showed me. His was distinctly more... 3D with each layer showing certain levels of frequency I think.

I fear I may be rambling here so hopefully someone gets what I mean and knows how to convey that.

Comment: The warning is at it is: you have imaginary numbers, which cannot be graphed really, hence they are discarded. Assuming that you have the same dataset as your supervisor, your method of plotting said complex numbers might be the ones at odds with his. Have you checked if the imaginary numbers are being used in any way by your supervisor in his plots, in any case?

Comment: I showed him the complex numbers generating by fft and he seemed content with them. He seemed to suggest that the result given by the rfft function could be used to generate a 3D graph. He isn't familiar with Python or any problems this may cause.

Comment: Imaginary numbers can be separated from real ones in `numpy`, even if they are stored in an array. Try looking at [this hastily written gist](https://gist.github.com/jerome-montino/c9d7ed976fc3a4c867e5) and check if it's even an approximation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is standard to plot the magnitude (use `abs(rfft(waveform))`) instead of the complex numbers.  Then rarely will people plot the phase. Using complex numbers wouldn't really give you a 3D graph anyway, but 2 2D graphs; though anything could be plotted in 3D if you try hard enough.  "each layer showing certain levels of frequency" sounds a bit like a spectrogram but shown with multiple curves instead of colors.. might that be what you want?

Comment: Yes! A spectogram and colours sounds right.

Comment: @Nanor: Check the gist I linked above. See if it's similar to the spectogram you want.